# PHP 5.3.3 - running session_start() in subdirectory kills existing session

Tags: php, session

I've been trying to track down some annoying session issues since my webhost upgrade to PHP 5.3.3 awhile back. I've determined that if there is an active session, calling session_start() from a subdirectory kills the existing session. As an example, I start a session and a user logs in to domain.com/index.php then the user navigates to domain.com/members/ which fires start_session() ... the user's session is lost.

I've dug around for this and can't find anything similar. Is there a PHP configuration that would account for this behavior?

Comment: This is a question you should be taking up with your host, configurations are different from host to host, kinda unanswerable.

Comment: I'm going down that route as well - but haven't had a lot of luck to this point.

Comment: I would think that a PHP session would be per-domain, not per-directory in most cases.

Comment: what are the cookie settings (e.g the session_set_cookie_params() settings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your sessions works all right within the same directory (it is unclear from your question),  there is the only possible reason for such a behavior, a pretty obvious one: "directory" cookie parameter.
It seems it is set to somewhat unusual value, other than default "/" for the session cookie parameter.
You have to check it out.

Anyway, it is almost useless to try ANY session/cookie related problem without an **HTTP interchange log**.
You have to use some HTTP sniffer, like LiveHTTPHeaders Firefox addon to see what cookie header was sent by the server and which one was returned by client.
Otherwise it's all going to be shooting in the dark.

---

Okay, as it seems from your yonder comment, the session id remains the same, so, no HTTP issue can be a reason. The issue become a kinda tricky to spot. 
Could you please post your test script here?

Comment: As I said - basic test script. With an existing session, firing this in the root directory retains the session array. In a subdir, the session array is lost. In both cases, the session id is retained.

 `session_start();`
 `print_r($_SESSION);`
 `echo session_id();`

Comment: errr... where do you set the session contents? Do you run the same test script both in root and subdir?

Comment: The session contents are being set on a login script fired in root. I did eliminate that script as the cause by conditionally setting `$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';` in the root version of the test script and bypassing the login script.

Comment: For what it's worth, most webkit browsers including Safari and Chrome have a very good log in the "Network" tab of the web inspector. It will show you every header sent/received for a page load.

Comment: @SDG please, create a DISTINCT version of the test code. WITHOUT any interverence with your other code.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - Just for clarity, I did create a distinct version of the test code without using the login script to set the initial session data. The results were the same

Comment: what is the code? and what is the result for the directory itself? does it keep the data set inside?

Comment: `session_start();`

`if (!$_SESSION['test']) {`
`$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';`
`}`

`print_r($_SESSION);`

That is setting the session data in root - I'm not setting the session data inside the subdir as it defeats the purpose.
echo session_id();

Comment: for the debugging purpose you have to test the session in the subdir as well. you are debugging now, not writing your program. the only your purpose now is to make sessions work.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well. If I set session data in the subdir (using the same method as above, but different values), the session data is set - the old session data is overwritten. As an example I define `$_SESSION['test'] = 'test'` in root and `$_SESSION['testSubdir'] = 'testSubdir'` in the subdir - the values are set, but the previous value is lost. This goes both ways, moving to the subdir and from root and back.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `session_start()` multiple times with that version of PHP shouldn't cause any problems, however there are other possible causes.

One possible explanation is that the client's browser isn't sending the session id back to the server. You can test this out by comparing the session id that both pages produce. Assuming that you have a controlled environment where you can test this properly, you can use [`session_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) to get the session.

It might also be that the user is hitting a different webserver. Since (by default) PHP stores sessions to disk, there is no way for multiple servers to share the session information. If this is a shared host, it's probably quite unlikely this is the cause. You can test this out however by using `phpinfo()`. It should give you enough information to determine if it's the same server or not. For multi-server systems, I'd look at storing sessions in memcache or mysql.

Comment: Good thoughts. The session id is being retained but the $_SESSION global array is emptied when I run session_start() in a subdirectory. As a test, I created a simple script that I duplicated in the root and /includes directories. When fired within the root directory, the session is retained and the session array is printed.  In the sub directory the session ID stays the same, but the session array is empty.

Comment: is the `session_name()` the same as well?

Answer (score 1):

I've spent quite a long time searching, trying, testing for what looked like the same problem. As google kept sending me here, I think sharing the solution might help others (though I feel strange posting on a 2011 question):

Session variables set in `/bar.php` were not set in `/foo/foobar.php`.

It realised that the issue had nothing to do with folder/subfolder when I finally found out that the link in `http://www.example.com/bar.php` was pointing to `http://example.com/foo/foobar.php` (missing `www`).

Correcting the URL in the html link solved the problem. Having no time to dig deeper, what I can figure out is that *(in my config)* Apache makes no difference and serves pages indifferently with and without `www`, whereas PHP doesn't share the session between what it considers being two different domains, `example.com` and `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a PHP configuration that would account for this behavior?

Yes, if the storage for the session data differs between those calls, the `$_SESSION` content will differ as well. The storage can be configured, see http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php for all configuration options you have with sessions.

Next to that if PHP is unable to read the session store, you will get an empty array as well.

I can't tell you if this is the issue with your problem, but probably it's helpful.

BTW, calling `session_start()` and than having an empty `$_SESSION` is commonly a sign that a new session has been created. You can verify this if you use cookies for your sessions and you output [`headers_list`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php):

```
echo '<pre>', var_dump(headers_list());
```

If it contains a new cookie for the session, the session has been created with this request.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good suggestions here. Thanks everyone. I spent a good chunk of the weekend digging into this and wasn't able to directly resolve it. I ended up demonstrating to my webhost that this problem happens on two of his hosted sites and doesn't happen in a default install of PHP. To work around the problem, I ended up moving all of my login and session logic into a single class.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share another answer, found in this SO: *[Session variables not accessible in subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822865/session-variables-not-accessible-in-subdirectory)* answered by **clayRay**.

My answer was that I had a custom "php.ini" file saved in the root directory, and moving those directives into `ini_set()` calls solved it.  You could also shove those over to `.htaccess` if your host allows.