# PHP Session Variable Set in Root not Visible in Subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, session, iis, subdirectory

I have Wordpress running on windows shared hosting (IIS) w/ Godaddy.  Wordpress is running out of it's own subdirectory "/wordpress".  If I set a PHP session value e.g.  $_SESSION["test1"] = "value set from root: /"; in PHP from root, I can see the session's value fine as long as my PHP code is running out of root. If I try and access this session value from the /wordpress folder, it is not found.

Vice versa applies.  If I set a session value under /wordpress and its subdirectories, I can view the session and its values great as long as I operate within the /wordpress folder. If I try and access the session value which was set from within /wordpress in root it is not accessible.

I've checked the session ids and they are both the same from root and from the /wordpress folder.  I've inspected the cookies set from both and they have the same path & domain.

I'm at a loss why setting PHP session values from root versus the /wordpress folder would not be global.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

/set_session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["test1"] = "value set from root: /";
?>
```

/wordpress/set_session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["test2"] = "value set from wordpress subdirectory: /wordpress";
?>
```

view_session.php (I run this from root and /wordpress)

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<h3> PHP List All Session Variables</h3>";
   foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$val)
    echo $key." ".$val."<br/>";
?>
```

If I run the view session script from /view_session.php I only see a value for "test1" as it was set from /set_session.php.

If I run the view session script from /wordpress/view_session.php I only see the value for "test2" as it was set from /wordpress/set_session.php.

Comment: What do you mean by "in PHP from root"? You can only set a session variable inside a script and it will be visible inside the context of that session. So most likely if you mean you set the variable in one script and then do not have it in another this means you refer to different sessions.

Comment: I have a php file/script in root, set a session value there.  I have another php file/script in /wordpress and set its session value there.  The sessions appear to be different as the values from each set are not both seen when viewing the session from either root or /wordpress.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I said. So the question appears to be why you are using different sessions? I suggest you post some code showing how you setup the sessions. Otherwise there is nothing we can help with...

Comment: I'm stoned, so I looked at this question for like 15 minutes. Still doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish? What do you mean by "access this session value from the /wordpress folder"? Who is accessing it, how? Wordpress? Are you saying a script A in Wordpress can't access Script B's session variables? huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say GoDaddy support is useless. They took the stance that because there was no official "error" that they could not help me and it was not their fault regardless of having sample basic code demonstrating the issue.

When I installed WordPress, I used their Plesk automated install option to install WP for me. It installed WordPress to its own sub-directory. This is fine, however their install processes made the /wordpress folder its own virtual directory which causes all content within it to run under its own app pool/thread. This caused the different sessions between the /wordpress directory and other directories within the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue because of a php.ini file in the root folder. The file had a single directive to change max_input_vars. I removed the file and set max_input_vars in cPanel instead, and then my session was suddenly shared correctly between subfolders. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779463/4370999