# PHP Session not working in sub directories

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I face this weird problem. I have a PHP page where I set the session variable. Then I load another page into the DIV tag of this page using $('').load(URL); But the page being loaded doesnt retain the session and destroys the current one as soon as its loaded. But the same page retains the session if its kept in the same directory along with the main page.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199936/php-5-3-3-running-session-start-in-subdirectory-kills-existing-session). But it doesn't provide any solution.

Here is my code
Main Page: sample.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
$_SESSION['test'] = "hello";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "<br>";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION["test"];
        ?>
        <div id="samedir" style="border: 1px solid #000;">

        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="subdir" style="border: 1px solid #000;">

        </div>
        <input type="button" value="hello" id="hellobtn"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#hellobtn').click(function() {
                $('#samedir').load("sample1.php");
                $('#subdir').load("forms/sample1.php");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Second Page: sample1.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    session_start();
echo session_id();
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
ob_flush();
?>
```

You can see here I have 2 load calls in Main page
$('#samedir').load("sample1.php"); 
this one loads from the same directory and dumps output

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" }
```

Whereas the second call `$('#subdir').load("forms/sample1.php");` dumps this:

```
array(0) { }
```

But everything works fine in my localhost (MAMP) but not in my hosting server. 
Thank you guys.

Comment: what If you just do your if statement + echo $_session['test'] on the sample1.php ?

Comment: Some spaces / new-lines before the opening php tag? You should enable error display and check the return value of `session_start()`. Also, your output does not seem to match the script, where is the session ID?

Comment: `sample1.php` : `session_start();` on any condition .. not only `if(!isset($_SESSION)) ` ..

Comment: @jeroen Hi i didnt copy the session ID when pasting here. But it matches as expected. sample.php: b1646cb8ab5190c1c55dc42a4b83f76e
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" } 
hello
b1646cb8ab5190c1c55dc42a4b83f76e
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "hello" }

b1646cb8ab5190c1c55dc42a4b83f76e
array(0) { }

Comment: @SyedQarib Hi I came to this condition after checking in another stackoverflow page. It gives the same result whether i use the condition or not.

Comment: @Julo0sS Hi I tried that as the first one? since it returned nothing I switched to var_dump to have a detailed output.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd page,
You must start session in 2nd line
Without any condition.

Answer (score -2):

A session creates a file in a temporary directory on the server where registered session variables and their values are stored. This data will be available to all pages on the site during that visit.

The location of the temporary file is determined by a setting in the php.ini file called session.save_path. so pleasse check this path.

Also [session-save-path()][1] Get and/or set the current session save path.

I think u dont need to write this line and check your php.ini for correct path.

for session i found some useful article http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm

The directory does not affect your session state (all directories of a given Apache-PHP website will access the same session in a standard configuration). You should not have to use session_save_path().

I think the problem in part is that you're setting 'uid' to itself ($_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid'];) - therefore potentially never actually setting it to a value - and potentially redirecting indefinitely if it's not set.

I suggest this simple test to ensure that your sessions are, in fact, working:

/session_set.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = 123;
```

/sub_dir/session_get.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['uid'];
```

Comment: Hi @Write thanks for the explanation. But kindly check the code above. I have not used anything like $_SESSION['uid'] = $_SESSION['uid']; In sample.php page i have set $_SESSION['test'] = "hello"; And in sample1.php page i have got echo $_SESSION['test']; after session start.