# PHP session does not work in sub directory & kills existing session

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, php-ini

I have 3 environments for PHP.

1. Local
2. Staging
3. Live

The issue is that when I calling session in sub directory after `session_start()` that gives error that **headers are already sent** & kills existing session. And If I do not start session then it gives error for **Undefined variable _SESSION**.

Session is working only in **ROOT** directory. but not work in **Subdirectory**.

This only occurs on **Live Environment**. This same code is working on **Local** & **Staging** but not on **Live**.

I don't know but this may be PHP configuration issue. Please guide me.

Comment: can you add the code where you start session in the sub directory

Comment: this question is same as [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199936/php-5-3-3-running-session-start-in-subdirectory-kills-existing-session)

Answer (score 1):

Add session_start() at the beginning of your main page.
Please ensure that if you are including some other file, session_start() is not defined there else error will display.

Comment: error is also displaying on my Local & Staging Environment. But they does not kills my session. Why my Live server kills existing session?

Answer (score 0):

The first line of php should be session_start(). If you include/add php page which contain session_start() into another page, it will show error "header already sent".

Add session_start() at the beginning of your page main page.

Comment: I have already started session on each and every page. this page is calling in iframe. The main page contains session_start() and iframe page also contains session_start(). but if i start session again it kills existing session. And If i don't start_session() on iframe page, It give error for undefined $_SESSION variable. at and it kills existing session.

Comment: IFrame create fully new http session. You cannot merge your main session with ifram session. You should not use iframe in this situation. I will suggest you to use div. You may use IFrame to load external page in your website.

Comment: I have try for that after your suggestion but actually that does not works. session is also killed in this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not solved this issue. but i have putted my key files which are required session data to my ROOT directory. And calling dependent files by different paths. Thanks for trying.